# Solve a linear equation system with non fixed coefficients

Tags: algorithm, linear-algebra

I'm searching for a library that can give a closed form solution to a quadratic linear equation system where the coefficients are not fixed. I.E.:

```
x1 +  1*x2 = a1
x1 - a2*x1 = 0
```

Where x1 and x2 are the variables and a1 and a2 are the coefficients. The solution to this system would be

```
x1 = (a1*a2)/(1+a2)
x2 = a1/(1+a2)
```

Is there a library in any language that can solve this automatically? All the libraries I found only worked for fixed coefficients.
Any tips are appreciated.

Comment: So you need symbolic algebra libraries? Look at SymPy for reference

Comment: @MBo yes, I think that is it. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need symbolic algebra. Use the determinant formulas for the solutions, one determinant in the numerator, another in the denominator. Each of them is a quadratic form in the a's and b's. This works just as well for n linear equations in n unknowns, but then each of them is an n-form.

I understand that you only need the solution for n=2. Here it is:

```
x1 = (b1 a22 - b2 a12) / (a11 a22 - a21 a12)
x2 = (a11 b2 - a21 b1) / (a11 a22 - a21 a12)
```

Comment: In fact I actually need this for arbitrary n, so this is quite useful! So I guess to automatically do this, I still need a symbolic determinant solver. If I understood correctly, in a quadratic linear equation system with n variables and a solution vector b, there are n+1 different determinants (Taking out the solution vector or the coresponding column of the variable)? And for the solution for a variable is
     x_i=det(A_i|b)/det(A)
where A_i is the coefficient matrix without column i.
Is that correct? :D

Comment: @MalteHeithoff I think you are right. In the formula for xi you replace the i'th column in A with b. Why do you need a symbolic determinant calculator? The formula for the determinant is det A = sum( (-1)^s as(1)1 as(2)2 ... as(n)n ) taken over all permutations s. When n is large there are horribly many terms! It isn't practical to compute it explicitly then.